# Google maps white striations / false artifacts

Tags: google-maps, google-earth, imagery

What are the common white striations running from NW to SE visible when you zoom in around 5mi scale? For example at [(+81, -80)](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=map++81,+-80)? But they appear 'all over'. Are they snow drifts? or satellite sweeps?

[image: Screen shot]

Generally: Where can I find documentation on Google Maps false artifacts?

Answer (score 2):

If you look carefully the striping runs across the whole image, although it is clearly more visible over the lake body (due to its particular reflectance in that moment). This is probably an image noise issue related to some problem on the satellite sensor that captured the image. Have a look at the following links for some more information about this:

- [Image Enhancement](http://academic.emporia.edu/aberjame/student/tucker1/es775.html)
- [Coherent Noise](http://landsat.usgs.gov/science_an_cn.php)

Answer (score 2):

Checking out the same spot in Google Earth gives an attribution to Landsat, so this data most likely came from [Landsat 7 with SLC-Off.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landsat_7#Scan_Line_Corrector_failure)

A small mirror broke on Landsat 7 that corrected for the ground movement of the satelite.  There are post-processing techniques that can partially repair the image, but they probably cause artifact like the ones you see.